# What is a safe way to drop a collection in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Does anyone know how to drop a collection safely in Meteor?  There doesn't seem to be an API method for this.  The collections are published, so I want to cleanup the associated data and functions (besides just removing the MongoDB collection).

Someone asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216752/dropping-a-mongo-database-collection-in-meteor) but no one actually answered it (just other concerns apart from dropping the collection).

Clarification: I need to do this from the meteor program at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop a collection with the basic mongo shell command : `db.collection.drop()`

To do that, you have to connect to your mongo shell in your command line.

There is another easier way : Robomongo ( http://robomongo.org/ ) which is a really nice GUI to manage mongo db. Once logged on mongo, just right click on your collection and then > drop (and confirm of course).

For example, to log in on your local environment, give any name and skip login. The address should be localhost : 3001.

Comment: Thank you but my meteor program needs to do it at runtime.  I edited my question to clarify that.